# Windows batch script to add characters in first row of every text file in a folder

Tags: windows, batch, textfiles

I need help with this.

I am new to bat files. I want to drop a number of text files into a folder on my Windows desktop. In that folder I want to have a bat file that will run on those text files. All I want the bat file to do is add the characters "$$ " (without quotes and with a space after the $$) to the existing first line, save the file, and then loop through the rest of the files in the folder.

So far I have the following:

```
@echo off
set "$New_line=$$ "
for /R "C:\Desktop\TEXT\" %%A in (*.txt) do (
  > "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA" echo %$New_line%
  type "%%A" >> "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA"
  del "%%A" 2>nul
  ren "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA" "%%~nxA"
)
```

But it adds a line with the characters that I need. I don't want to add a line but add the characters in front of the existing first line.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I `echo` a string with adding a CR/LF?

> ```
> > "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA" echo %$New_line%
> ```

You can use the following construct:

> ```
> <nul (set/p _any_variable=string to emit)
> ```

Source: [Echo - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)

So in your case, it would be something like:

```
> "%%~dpANew_%%~nxA" (set/p _any_variable=%$New_line%)
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Echo - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [Set - Environment Variable - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)